# Video streaming MPEG-2 data for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, streaming

I am working on video streaming for iPhone.
The case is i get data as integer multiple of 188 bytes in MPEG-2 format.

Can anyone please suggest me on on how to start on this case.

I searched a lot and got frustrated with it.

I would be absolutely thankful for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to get streaming video onto the iPhone is using HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) and the H264 codec. You'll have to transcode your stream on the server to this format. There are a number of server solutions that can do this, such as Wowza stream server or Helix server, among others.

I believe you can also have ffmpeg do this for you. The following might help
http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/

Comment: Actually my problem is that i am getting the MPEG-2 data from a third party Library directly into my app. Is it that i have to create some virtual server in my app to say which reads the incoming data from Third party library and produce some kind of stream to the MPMoviewplaer or any other player?

Comment: It's not going to be easy. I think your best bet would be to find a library that can decode MPEG2 stream data and then draw that yourself into a CoreVideo layer.